# sql trigger print message

Tags: sql, printing, triggers

I am new at using triggers in database, and I created some triggers that worked very well for me except that when I tried to create a trigger that will show a message after deleting a row.

I tried using this code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER "mycustomerTrigger" 
AFTER delete ON customers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
print 'trigger is working'
END
```

when I created this trigger it doesn't give error message, but when I delete a row it doesn't show the message that I print.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because of the way that triggers are run, basically it is not in your query execution window. One way of doing this is logging to the event viewer.

```
Create trigger TestTrigger on
tablefortrigger
for insert
as
–Declare variable to hold message
Declare @Msg varchar(8000)
–Assign to message “Action/Table Name/Time Date/Fields inserted
set @Msg = ‘Inserted | tablefortrigger | ‘ + convert(varchar(20), getdate()) + ‘ | ‘
+(select convert(varchar(5), track)
+ ‘, ‘ + lastname + ‘, ‘ + firstname
from inserted)
–Raise Error to send to Event Viewer
raiserror( 50005, 10, 1, @Msg)
```

Another way of doing this is to write to a file, there is of course permissions issues here, but you could do this:

```
Alter trigger TestTrigger on
tablefortrigger
for insert
as
Declare @Msg varchar(1000)
–Will hold the command to be executed by xp_cmdshell
Declare @CmdString varchar (2000)
set @Msg = ‘Inserted | tablefortrigger | ‘ + convert(varchar(20), getdate()) + ‘ — ‘
+(select convert(varchar(5), track)
+ ‘, ‘ + lastname + ‘, ‘ + firstname
from inserted)
–Raise Error to send to Event Viewer
raiserror( 50005, 10, 1, @Msg)
set @CmdString = ‘echo ‘ + @Msg + ‘ >> C:logtest.log’
–write to text file
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @CmdString
```

More information can be found here: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/log-file-trigger/

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do it in a lightweight way that doesn't require viewing the server log, raising errors or setting special permissions, you can just create a table that holds one column for your logs:

`create table logs (logstring nvarchar(max))`

and log to it like this:

`insert into logs`
`values ('hello')`

Comment: if the trigger fails, will the log insert be rolled back ?

Comment: Logging into another table when a trigger fails will not succeed.