# SQL Server trigger info insert in another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I created a table `tblAddress` and I want to use a trigger. When I `INSERT/DELETE` or `UPDATE`, these changes should be saved in another table - in a lock table. I am a beginner in SQL Server, can you please help me with this problem?

I just did this much. The other table I want to store trigger information in, is named `tr_Lock`.

```
Create Trigger tr_tblAddress_ForInsertDeleteUpdate
On tblAddress
After Insert,Delete,Update
As
    Print 'You Deleted, Inserted, Updated one row from tblAddress';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql trigger print message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853153/sql-trigger-print-message)

Comment: @Lankymart FWICT the OP wants store auditing information to a specific table, not really print out information.

Comment: Looks like a typo after `After` should be `After, `

Comment: @TT I'm going off the code provided. They may indeed to be trying to do that but if they are testing it by passing `PRINT` then wondering why it's not working that question will help.

Comment: It may just be text, but your trigger is already incorrect. In SQL Server, triggers fire once per *statement*, not once per *row*. So when a trigger fires, it may be in response to 0, 1 or *multiple* rows having been deleted, inserted or updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers fire once per statement not once per row.Triggers have access to inserted ,deleted tables which you can use as per your requirements.

After insert has access to newly inserted rows,After delete has access to deleted rows,after update has access to deleted rows as well newly updated rows.

please see below simple example

```
create table triggertest
(
id int,
name char(1)
)

create table log
(
id int,
name char(1),
operationdone char(2),
loggedtime datetime
)

Alter trigger trg_test1
on triggertest
after insert,update,delete
as
begin

set nocount on

--insert updated rows
if exists(select 1 from inserted) and exists(select 1 from deleted)
begin

insert into log
select *,'U',getdate() from inserted
return

end


----insert new rows
if exists(select 1 from inserted)
begin
insert into log
select *,'I',getdate() from inserted
return
end

--insertd deleted rows
if exists(select 1 from deleted)
begin

insert into log
select *,'D',getdate() from deleted

return
end



end


insert into triggertest
select 1,'z'

update triggertest
set 
id=2 
where name='z'

delete from triggertest


select * from log
select * from triggertest



 id name operationdone  loggedtime
    1   z       I              2016-03-08 19:54:23.617
    2   z       U              2016-03-08 19:54:30.373
    2   z       U              2016-03-08 19:54:30.373
    2   z       D              2016-03-08 19:54:39.063
    2   z      D               2016-03-08 19:54:39.063
```

Comment: Thank you TheGameiswar for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample data for your case

```
    CREATE TABLE BILL (BILL_NBR INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, BILL_NME VARCHAR(50),CREATE_DTE DATETIME, MODIFY_DTE DATETIME)
    GO
    CREATE TABLE LOG_BILL (LOG_BILL_NBR INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, LOG_DTE DATETIME, BILL_NBR INT, BILL_NME VARCHAR(50)
    ,CREATE_DTE DATETIME, MODIFY_DTE DATETIME)
    GO
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_BILL_LOG] ON [dbo].BILL 

    AFTER UPDATE,DELETE
    AS

    INSERT INTO LOG_BILL (LOG_DTE,BILL_NBR,BILL_NME,CREATE_DTE,MODIFY_DTE)
    SELECT I.MODIFY_DTE, D.BILL_NBR, D.BILL_NME, D.CREATE_DTE, D.MODIFY_DTE  FROM DELETED D
    LEFT JOIN INSERTED I ON D.BILL_NBR = I.BILL_NBR

    GO

    INSERT INTO BILL
    SELECT 'A',GETDATE(), GETDATE()
    GO
    UPDATE BILL SET BILL_NME='B' WHERE BILL_NBR=1
    GO
    SELECT * FROM LOG_BILL
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of setting up your trigger to work for insert, update and delete

```
USE StackOverflow
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblAddress', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.tblAddress

CREATE TABLE tblAddress
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Address] VARCHAR(128)
)

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblAddressAudit', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.tblAddressAudit

CREATE TABLE tblAddressAudit
(
    Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    AddressID INT,
    [Address] VARCHAR(128),
    AuditDate DATETIME, 
    [Action] CHAR(1)
)

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tblAddress_audit_trigger', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER dbo.tblAddress_audit_trigger
GO



CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tblAddress_audit_trigger
ON dbo.tblAddress
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.tblAddressAudit
        SELECT d.Id AS AddressID, d.[Address], GETDATE() AuditDate, 'D' [Action]
        FROM deleted d
        LEFT JOIN inserted i ON i.Id = d.Id
        WHERE i.Id IS NULL
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.tblAddressAudit
        SELECT i.Id AS AddressID, i.[Address], GETDATE() AuditDate, 'I' [Action]
        FROM inserted i
        LEFT JOIN deleted d ON i.Id = d.Id
        WHERE d.Id IS NULL
    END
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted i JOIN deleted d on i.Id = d.Id)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.tblAddressAudit
        SELECT i.Id AS AddressID, i.[Address], GETDATE() AuditDate, 'U' [Action]
        FROM inserted i 
        JOIN deleted d on i.Id = d.Id
    END
END

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.tblAddress
VALUES
(
'42 Goble street'
)
GO

UPDATE dbo.tblAddress
SET [Address] ='43 Goble St'
WHERE Id = 1
GO

DELETE FROM dbo.tblAddress
WHERE Id = 1
GO
```

Comment: Thank you TYY for your help.