# Creating a text log of SQL transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging

I have script that is to delete an ID and its associated records across a number of tables. What I am looking for is a way to print out all the individual transactions. I haven't been able to figure that out so I am instead running a select statement to populate a temp table with the values that will be deleted. The problem I have is I cannot figure a way to display my new temp table.

For example, one delete is as follows:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Attachments WHERE IdeaID IN (SELECT IdeaID FROM #Ideas)
```

With #Ideas being a table that holds the various IDs I want removed. The tables have 0..* records for each ID. So to see those records I can run this select:

```
SELECT * INTO #Attachments FROM dbo.Attachments WHERE IdeaID IN (SELECT IdeaID FROM #Ideas)
```

Now the problem is how do I display this?

I attempted to utilize PRINT:

```
DECLARE @PRINTATTEMPT varchar(max)
SET @PRINTATTEMPT='select * from #Attachments'
EXEC(@PRINTATTEMPT)
PRINT(@PRINTATTEMPT)
```

Unfortunately all this PRINTS is the SQL statement itself, not the values.

Next I attempted to get tricky with a cursor to iterate and print line by line:

```
DECLARE @DISPLAYVALUES nvarchar(128)

DECLARE attachmentscur CURSOR FOR
SELECT * FROM #Attachments

OPEN attachmentscur

FETCH NEXT FROM attachmentscur INTO @DISPLAYVALUES;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
PRINT 'Attachment selected for removal: ' + @DISPLAYVALUES
FETCH NEXT FROM attachmentscur INTO @DISPLAYVALUES;
END

CLOSE attachmentscur;
DEALLOCATE attachmentscur;
```

Unfortunately with this I am then hit with the error "Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns." I think this is trying to tell me it doesn't know how to iterate through the table... but I'm not sure.

Again - so this makes some sense, I have two dozen or so tables that I need to delete records from. Each utilizes this ID filed and I simply want to create a log of what is removed (just a local txt file). The log cannot be saved in the database so backup tables are not a possibility.

Comment: Why do you need a cursor here at all? If this is just a one time thing can't you just run a select statement to get the rows you are going to delete and stick the results in your text file?

Comment: I don't need a cursor if there is another way. This is however something I would need to run often across a number of instances. I could run two dozen or so select statements each time but that would quickly become tedious...

Comment: I don't see how it would be any more tedious than what you are doing now. It isn't like the print statement will output to a file. You just have a listing of the data that you will have to copy/paste. Seems the same to me but no cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Going on the route that you have set, your last attempt is a good one, but you need to fix your FETCH INTO stateament: you need to provide one variable for each column or create a record type that will correspond to each column.

In complete different way to get this solved, you can use triggers BEFORE DELETE saving the needed information into a log table or something...

Comment: See this for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853153/sql-trigger-print-message